# CTCall with Bluetooth or Handsfree

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm looking for a way to detect if a call is made using a handsfree device or the user is making a regular call (without any external device connected). I guess I can do it indirectly with the CoreBluetooth but this don't gonna work with iPhone 4 and 3GS. I'm also not sure if using AVAudioPlayer class could work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I want to answer myself, just for the record. It's impossible to know directly if a call is made trough Bluetooth or any other way. But you can ask where is the audio is transmitting using the AudioToolBox framework (any kind of audio). This script helps a lot!

https://github.com/Jawbone/AudioSessionManager